# Why is the energy of a light wave not dependent on amplitude?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

When searched up on Google, the formula for the energy of an electromagnetic wave is E = hv, wherein h is Planck's Constant, and v is it's frequency.

Why is amplitude not included in this equation? Since higher amplitude is correspondent to brighter light, isn't that more energy?

If amplitude doesn't affect energy, what does it affect?

Comment: because EM waves are made from tiny atoms/electrons and molecules one at a time .... so the formula is for single photons.   In a radio antenna we can make many electrons move/accelerate  in the same direction and get a big wave .... but it is really made of many small waves.

Answer (score 3):

> the formula for the energy of an electromagnetic wave is E = hv,

That is not correct. The formula cited is the formula for the energy of a single photon. An electromagnetic wave can contain an arbitrary number of photons. So the energy of an electromagnetic wave is the sum of the energies of all of the photons contained in the wave.

For a large number of photons, such that quantum effects are negligible, this sum leads to the classical amplitude.

Comment: Oh! I see. Thank you very much. In that case, individual photons can have frequencies and thus different energies, and a wave is like a generalisation, wherein the amplitude of a classical wave is the sum of these energies. (Is that correct?) In that case, if you have photons with differing frequencies, what is the frequency of the wave?

Comment: @Jonathan such a wave would have multiple frequencies. Waves are not restricted to a single frequency.